# Creating a dummy v4l2 capture device without using 'v4l2loopback'

Tags: 20.04, raspberrypi, playonlinux, video-streaming, v4l

Can i create a dummy v4l2 video device just like done by `sudo modprobe v4l2loopback` without using v4l2loopback via command line.I don,t want to use v4l2loopback because it is not able to call a function in my application .Any other command line solution will be highly appreciated .Main aim is to just **stream a prestored video over a v4l2 video device**.
I am currently using ubuntu on RaspberryPi4.

Thanks in advance for your effort and time.